# Webpack-cli for Laravel mix needed?

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, webpack, webpack-cli

I took a look at [Laravels official package.json](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/package.json) to update mine which goes back to Laravel 5.4. Mine looked like [this](https://pastebin.com/HKRnCfiw) and I updated it to look like [this](https://pastebin.com/y1QSa9Jx). I removed node, webpack and webpack-cli, because apparently it is not needed? However, I get this error:

```
.../node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:93
                                throw err;
                                ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'js' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (.../webpack.mix.js:14:5)
```

Why does it refer to webpack-cli? I'm not quite sure how node and webpack etc. are related to Laravel here and what to do about it?